# Proof that if $x,z > 0,\ x+z < 1,\ (1+x)\times (1+z) \leq \frac{1}{(1-(x+z))}$

Tags: inequality

I am working through a textbook  and I just can't wrap my head arround how to prove this inequality. How would you go about doing it?
This is the excercise:

Proof that if $x,z > 0,\ x+z < 1:\\ (1+x)\times (1+z) \leq  \frac{1}{(1-(x+z))}$

Comment: Are you sure you got that right? You have a condition on some $y$ but you don't use it in the inequality?

Comment: I'm guessing $z=y$.

Comment: Since $0<x+z<1$, you may write the RHS as a geometric serie and note that the LHS is just contained in this serie. I mean, expanding the first three element in this series you get the LHS+something positive, hence the thesis.

Comment: @Macavity My bad. You guys are of course right. Edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $0<x<1$ then
$$0<1+x={1-x^2\over 1-x}<{1\over 1-x}\ ,$$
and similarly if $0<z<1$. If, in addition, $x+z<1$ then
$$(1+x)(1+z)<{1\over(1-x)(1-z)}<{1\over 1-(x+z)}\ .$$

Comment: You made it look laughably easy, thanks. Really need some more excercise in this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: since $x+z<1$, then $1-(x+z) > 0$. If that's true, then what operation can you perform in this equality that will make it much easier, albeit more tedious, to work with? Also: based on your initial conditions on $x$ and $z$, can you give an upper bound for them? It doesn't have to be too specific, but you can name an integer that neither of them can exceed.